# Unable to log-in using Ubuntu One Files with the Android application

Tags: ubuntu-one, android, files, login

I installed the Ubuntu One Files Android app to my phone(Samsung I5800). I have tried to register a number of times however, each time after signing in using my phone's browser I see a "We couldn't find that page" notification with no instructions on how to register.

After logging out from Ubuntu One from my phone's browser, I try to log in through the app again but I get a "Log-in failed, please try again later" prompt.

Can someone please help me with this before my business trip is ruined, I encouraged my boss to switch our cloud over from Dropbox to Ubuntu One and now I can't upload important documents and photos of samples to the cloud !

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for answering so late (I don't hang out on askubuntu, perhaps I should..). The issues you were having where caused by time setting of the device / time difference between the phone and the server. These have been fixed in 1.0.3.1 version (unless the user unchecks the 'Automatic' checkbox at the top of "Date & time" device settings).

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the password and check if Ubuntu One Mobile works if connecting to a wifi hotspot